# How to start a terminal, so that on exit will call a function?

Tags: terminal-buffer

I recorded info of terminal buffers in a dict, and want remove bufnr of closed ones.

Can you tell me **how to start a terminal such that call a function on exit, eg,**

```
func! myterm#remove(bufnr):
    call remove(s:terms, a:bufnr)
endfunc
```

Comment: you probably need to use `term_start()` and use the `callback` options for this specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is using `job-exit_cb` handler, (see `:help job-exit_cb`)

A working example is

```
func! g:Exit_cb(job, exit_code)
    echo term_getjob(2)
    let pid = matchstr(a:job, '^\%(process \)\zs\d\+')
    echom "job " . pid . " finished with exit_code " . a:exit_code
endfunc

call term_start('bash', {'exit_cb': function('g:Exit_cb')})
```

Run above code, then close the newly created terminal, you will see
something like below

```
job 61392 finished with exit_code 0
```

be echoed at the bottom, you can also verify with `:mess` command. *(since `:echom is used)*